# <DIV> and Shadowbox

Tags: html, css, shadowbox

I have a div centered on my page (width and height set, margin:auto). I am then adding images into it, and each image launches its own Shadowbox. However, there are two problems:

1. The shadowbox - while taking up the entire screen - is offset to the right side of the page. How do I get it back to center as if there was no div?
2. Each successive time I open a shadowbox on any given image (either all the same image or different image on each open), the shadowbox gets smaller. I didn't have this problem until I put the images inside the div.

You can see it in action [here](http://aterrell-www.cs.wisc.edu/search/so.php).

When I run it using the available Firefox consoles, I see a lot of warnings about fetching the height and width (presumably of the image). That partially explains the problems, but I'm not sure of the solution.

Source:

```
<html>
<head>
    <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../shadowbox-3.0.3/shadowbox.css">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../shadowbox-3.0.3/shadowbox.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        Shadowbox.init();
    </script>
</head>

<body>
    <div id="pageDiv" style="background-color:#FFFFFF">

        <a href="http://www.sport2play.com/baseball/pics/1.jpg" alt="none" rel="shadowbox"><img src="http://www.sport2play.com/baseball/pics/1.jpg" width="100px"/></a>
    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

For what it's worth, the CSS:

```
@font-face{
 font-family:"Officina";
 src:url(OfficinaSansStd-Book.otf);
}
body{
 font-family:"Officina";
 background-color:#AAAAAA;
}
img{
 box-shadow: 3px 3px 7px #777;
 background-color:#FFFFFF;
}
canvas{
 background-color:#FFFFFF;
}
div{
 width:500;
 height:647;
 margin:auto;
}
```

Thoughts on how to fix these two problems?

Comment: Might not be your problem, but you should really specify px or something for your div width, height.

Comment: Ah, sorry - that was there, and it got removed at some point when fiddling with those numbers. Still doesn't fix it though. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use doctype:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
```

It solves your 1st problem.

Comment: Actually, my div is still offset, even with this. Did it fix it for you?